# Intercept system.out in java

Tags: java, system

I have a method that has system.out and it's used in main. How can I intercept that print and assign it to a String variable? I also do not want it to be printed.

```
public void print()
System.out.println("hello");

---main---
print(); // need to intercept this 
String str = print(); // need assign the contents of the print() to str and not show the contents of print in the console
```

Edit: Due to some restrictions, I cannot create .txt and I cannot change the code of the method. I need to make all the changes in main

Comment: set it to a `PrintWriter` pointing to a `StringWriter`

Comment: @dan1st Sorry can you elaborate with code?

Comment: If you possibly can, change the code so as not to use any global state. (Otherwise, `System.setOut`.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline which code? I'm not sure what do you mean by a global state

Comment: @Ernest The code which uses `System.out`. Replace it with code that will print to a passed in `PrintStream` object (or object of similar type). / *Global state* is usually in the form of `static` variables hidden somewhere. It just means variable state that is not local.

Comment: I want to redirect to my own PrintWriter.  The question that "already has answers" is entitled as directing to a string, and leads with a discussion about void return method, neither of which are relevant to my question.  This question is phrased in a way that is more helpful for me, the other question is not.   That's maybe why _this_ question comes up top of the search results in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`System.setOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) to change the [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) used by `System.out`. You probably also want to call [`setErr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-) to the same `PrintStream`.

To illustrate, let us use a standard "Hello World" program.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

*Output*

```
Hello World
```

We now replace the output print stream with a print stream that captures all the output in a buffer. We do keep a copy of the original print stream so we can print something for real at the end.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream oldSysOut = System.out;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outBuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (PrintStream sysOut = new PrintStream(outBuf, false, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        System.setOut(sysOut);
        System.setErr(sysOut);
        
        // Normal main logic goes here
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
    String output = new String(outBuf.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    oldSysOut.print("Captured output: \"" + output + "\"");
}
```

*Output*

```
Captured output: "Hello World
"
```

As can be seen here, all the output was captured, including the linebreak from the `println()` call.

Comment: any idea why the normal System.outprintln() doesn't work afterwards?